# Installing vim with python3 support on MacOS 13 (Ventura)

Tags: python-3.x, macos, vim, homebrew, macos-ventura

I hope all are well. I found out that vim on my machine wasn't supporting python3:

```
vim --version | grep python
+cmdline_hist      -langmap           -python            +viminfo
+cmdline_info      +libcall           -python3           +virtualedit
```

I tried installing vim again with `brew install vim` but it is showing:

```
Warning: You are using macOS 13.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Twitter or any other official channels. You are responsible for resolving
any issues you experience while you are running this
pre-release version.

Error: vim: no bottle available!
You can try to install from source with:
  brew install --build-from-source vim
Please note building from source is unsupported. You will encounter build
failures with some formulae. If you experience any issues please create pull
requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub, Twitter or any other
official channels.
```

Comment: Which version of vim do you use? With ```Vim 9.0 MacOS Version - x86_64``` it seems to work (Installed via Homebrew).

Comment: Solved it! Upgrading the outdated packages has done the trick! Thank you, all.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it! Upgrading the outdated packages has done the trick! Thank you, all.
This doesn't work.

This worked:

```
brew remove vim
brew cleanup
brew install vim -vd protobuf
```